# appium-uiautomator2-server-v0.1.8.apk' exited with code 1" while getting badging info

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium

I am trying to learn Appium, using the instructions given in the documentation:

http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/?lang=en

I have put this code into a file called AppiumTest.js

```
const wdio = require('webdriverio');

const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8.0",
    deviceName: "Pixel_API_26",
    app: "C:/Users/SStaple/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ApiDemos-debug.apk",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2"
  }
};

const client = wdio.remote(opts);

client
  .init()
  .click("~App")
  .click("~Alert Dialogs")
  .back()
  .back()
  .end();
```

I am running it from the Node.js command prompt, using the command: node AppiumTest.js, after starting the Appium Server. It was also necessary to have an Android 8 emulator running.

(Appium Server v1.7.1)

I am getting an output in the Appium Server window. There are a number of errors. The first error shown is this:

```
Error "Command 'C\:\\Users\\SStaple\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\26.0.2\\aapt.exe d badging C\:\\Users\\SStaple\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\uiautomator2\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v0.1.8.apk' exited with code 1" while getting badging info
```

I have tried running this command on its own in the Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe d badging C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\uiautomator2\appium-uiautomator2-server-v0.1.8.apk
```

The result I get here is this:

```
W/zipro   (13656): Error opening archive C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\uiautomator2\appium-uiautomator2-server-v0.1.8.apk: Invalid file
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

Any ideas?

**Update 28/12/2017 - I found the solution!**

The file in question looked suspect. It was 0Kb in size!
I downloaded the apk file from https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-server/releases and used that instead.
This one is 1,518 KB in size.
(Apparently there is some problem with npm not putting that apk file into the right place while beta is installed.)

Having fixed that, I can move on to the next problem!

Comment: which appium version are you trying with ?

Comment: @Manidroid I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Its a [known issue](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-7-1-canot-singin-appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidtest-apk/19233/4) with apk signing.

You can start with trying to update dependencies:

```
npm install appium-uiautomator2-driver
npm install appium-adb
```

If it didn't help, there is more you can try (but that was for Linux):

modify
`./node-v6.11.4-linux-armv7l/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/build/lib/tools/apk-signing.js` so it would return a true even if it looks not signed.

```
case 20: 
 context$1$0.prev = 20;
 context$1$0.t0 = context$1$0’catch’; 
 _loggerJs2[‘default’].debug(“App not signed with debug cert.”); 
 return context$1$0.abrupt(‘return’, true);
```

Comment: I tried all of that. I edited C:\AppiumTesting\node_modules\appium-adb\build\lib\tools\apk-signing.js as well. It did not make any difference. First error is still the same: Error "Command 'C\:\\Users\\SStaple\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools\\26.0.2\\aapt.exe d badging C\:\\Users\\SStaple\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\appium-desktop\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-uiautomator2-driver\\uiautomator2\\appium-uiautomator2-server-v0.1.8.apk' exited with code 1" while getting badging info

Comment: dmle - I have checked out your 'known issue', but I fail to see the similarity? There is no mention here of 'badging'!!!